# Is there a YouTube for writers? Basically a way to share manuscripts on social media

Tags: fiction, book, criticism, social-media

The title explains it.

I'm looking for a place to post my writing and easily share it onto Facebook or Twitter. I know there are  A LOT of websites, but it seems like there are too many.

I'm looking to share chapters from a book I plan on writing, or even parts of a chapter.

What are some of the best ones to use?

Comment: Probably not what you are wanting, but it might be best to open a Facebook page that is for marketing your book and provide excerpts from it as posts.  I actually liked a page because of the quotes it was putting out, not realizing that this guy is actually trying to market his book as well and plan to buy it because of the excerpts.

Comment: I am a coder and a writer. What would you want from a writing website? I'm interested in building a platform for writers to share their work and get feedback. What features would you like if I were to create such a service? Figment is ok, it's not great, but it did a lot of things right. See what comes of their merge with Underlined.

Comment: @VicAlfieri, I'm learning to code, would you be interested in working on something together?

Comment: YouTube probably isn't a good example of what you want, both because the visual medium was given special handling and because YouTube now is not YouTube then.  How many videos do you see now which are not part of some big production?

Answer (score 2):

What distinguishes YouTube  is not the number of contributors, though that is huge, and essential to its success, but the number of viewers, which is extraordinarily large. What makes a content platform is always its appeal to consumers. For any content platform, the primary appeal to producers is that it has a lot of consumers.

YouTube is a great platform for consuming short videos. There is a huge appetite for short videos, but mostly for technical communication (how to do stuff) and music. The platform for long videos is not YouTube (though they seem to by trying), it is Netflix.

Viewing YouTube is all about short experiences and frequent shifts. It works well in a browser or on a phone. Viewing NetFlix is all about sitting back on the couch with a box of popcorn to watch a movie on a big screen. It is a different experience requiring a different platform.

In the book world, the nearest equivalent platform to Netflix is Kindle. They are both about the long-form sit back and enjoy experience.

There is no market for short fiction. There hasn't been one for decades, not since the demise of the classic family magazine market. Short stories are now apprentice pieces sold for no money to enthusiast magazines and webzines that no one reads. Thus there is no role for a short-form fiction exchange the way there is a role for a short form largely non-fiction video service like YouTube. And the YouTube model is not the right one for long form content of any kind.

Finally, there is no need for a similar platform for most forms of short-form non-fiction writing (technical communication, marketing) because Google provides all the navigation you need to find that stuff.

There is, however, a platform for a particular kind of short form non-fiction: questions and answers. You are using it now. Stack Exchange is probably the closest analog we have to YouTube for textual content.

Comment: I believe you may have miss read the question.  OP isn't looking for where he can put his short story, he is looking for a place where he can share excerpts/chapter samples from his novel which he can then turn into a marketing platform  by having said website share it to his facebook page to get the word out about the book.

Comment: @ggiaquin, Which, as I am pointing out, is not what YouTube does.

Comment: I do have a differing opinion about that though.  Podcasts are huge on Youtube.  Many people host shows on their channel to talk about politics/games/news/science etc.  He could very easily create a weekly/monthly podcast where he explains his book to viewers while doing chapter readings / excerpt readings like authors used to do when going to book stores to market their books.  A 10  minute video should easily cover a chapter/cliff hanger excerpt and provide any form of supporting dialog with it.

Comment: @ggiaquin He could certainly do that, but I doubt there is an audience for it. You can set up a hot dog stand at a vegan convention. You will get a lot of traffic but not many sales.

Comment: All I'm looking to do is easily share my writing, I'm currently not worried about any marketing or sales.  

I didn't bother to reply to the long "answer" above because it felt like it was going off on some tangent. Why bother addressing something that's not helping, right?  

I'm only replying now because I don't want any assumptions to be made or for my intent to get twisted.

Comment: @00Saad then I suggest you remove the misleading reference to YouTube from your question.

Comment: No, I'm going to keep it. YouTube is just a place to share videos, and I was just looking for a place to share writing.

Comment: @00Saad Not so much anymore, methinks.  You remember what YouTube was like 8 years ago?  Videos like that are there, but they average >1000 views each and are crowded by more popular videos unless users with cookies will cross-reference them together by being linked from elsewhere.  YouTube was, and is, more about browsing videos than simply hosting them.

Comment: @00Saad, no, it is far far more than a place to share videos. It is not about letting people share videos, it is about letting them find videos. Yes, it lets amateurs post crappy videos that no one watches, but it is primarily a platform on which professionals find an audience and audiences find high quality content. It is a professional publishing platform that simply lets the slush sink to the bottom rather than filtering it out. The nearest equivalent of that for fiction writers is KDP.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the reference to youtube means you're after something video based, but if not, then I think Scribophile is one of the best online places to share work for feedback:

https://www.scribophile.com/

For sharing it onto Facebook or Twitter, if you mean for publicity purposes, Hootsuite is a good platform where you can schedule updates for multiple feeds from a single place.

If you just want to share your work for people to read (as opposed to give you feedback on), then your best bet is a blog. [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com) is the most popular, but is not necessarily as intuitive as they make out. However, the ease of connecting with other people probably makes it your best best. If you don't like it you could try [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com).

Comment: +1 for the mentioning of a blog, however, I don't believe scribophile is what he is looking for.  To me, this feels more like a marketing question in regards to wanting to provide samples out to the world and have it link to a FB account dedicated to his book for marketing purposes.  I could be wrong but that is how I interpreted this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a long time to find such a site that was actually good, but I've failed. It seems most of them are either for professionals (people who already have books published) or are for amateur teens who claim their rewrites of Twilight and Divergent are "original"

There was this one place, Figment, that was alright. I heard it's shutting down this year and they're rebooting it. It was okay enough. You could post your work and get reviews and chat about writing in the forums. However, it was difficult to get attention for your work unless you a) were super popular b) managed to become your own graphic designer and create the best freaking cover ever!

I would suggest looking into that and then what comes out after its shut down and remade. Although it had its flaws, it was pretty casual and there were no strict rules for who could/couldn't post.

Comment: I'm pretty upset to hear that.

It seems that if you want to make videos or post pictures you have a ton of resources, but writers in general have to bust our humps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Wattpad (https://www.wattpad.com/home)
I don't use the platform myself, but for what I can see, it allows you to upload chapters of your book up to the full book, give a cover and some metadata, and share it with the community.

Everybody can read your text and comment snippets of it, creating engagement with the community members - this I believe is the nicest feature.

You can browse books by genre, and see statistics for each one (reads, likes, lists in which it's included, etc.)

Every language has its own community, so you can easily share your book to the specific audience of your language. It's not english-only.

Sometimes you read articles in the newspapers about writers who signed deals with publishers after receiving many views on Wattpad, so this gives some promotional push to the website.

Reading your question, I believe that is as close as you can get to something like YouTube.

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: Following your inputs, I elaborated my answer further. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's forums, where you can post excerpts of your work for critique, there's Figment, which is merging with a service called Underlined, there's DeviantArt, which is mostly for artists, and not exclusively (and harder to upload work) for writers, and there's Wattpad.

All of those options have their advantages and disadvantages.

Wattpad is very fan fiction focused.

Figment is very reliant on having to give feedback to others before getting any good feedback.

Deviant Art is harder for writers to upload work to than it is for the illustrators and digital artists it was created for,

And the forums are spotty with feedback and not always accommodating to newer members.

As for my offer to create a service that would allow users to get feedback for their writing and such, it's very much just an idea at the moment; as there's already a lot of services that offer the same sort of thing.

However, having used a good lot of those services, none them really worked well, except for one that doesn't exist anymore.

So, to answer your question, there's services which writers can use to share their work and get feedback, but not a lot of good ones, and even the good ones aren't that good.